# How do I create a graph from JSON data in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, highcharts

In a Ruby on Rails app deployed to Heroku, I'm trying to get a simple graph to display. Right now I'm using Highcharts but am open to trying anything that will get a graph on the screen with the correct data.

Here is the JSON data generated from an ActiveRecord from a Heroku postgres database:

```
[
   {
      "id" => 1,
      "height" => "5",
      "weight" => "450",
      "body_fat" => "51",
      "created_at" => Tue, 29 Jan 2019 02:06:59 UTC +00:00,
      "updated_at" => Tue, 29 Jan 2019 02:06:59 UTC +00:00,
      "user_id" => 1
   }
]
```

I want a graph that plots the weight element against the updated_at element. There might be several data points that are on the same day and I want to only graph the most recent one on that day. I tried Chartkick with groupdate but Heroku does not like groupdate.

Comment: Please post your code try with this.

Comment: @astronat can you try with the high-chart library

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts are appropriate for your needs. You will only have to convert date "created_at" to a timestamp in milliseconds. Check demo and API links posted below.

**Code:**

```
series: [{
    data: [
      [1264982400000, 29.9], // [timestamp, value]
      [1267401600000, 71.5],
      [1270080000000, 106.4]
    ]
}]
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/akyu3erb/

API reference:

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data.x